# Compute $\sum\limits _{j=2}^\infty\left(\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\:k^{-j}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Compute $\displaystyle\sum _{j=2}^{\infty }\left(\sum _{k=2}^{\infty }\:k^{-j}\right)$

I don't really know where to start. I can see that the inner series is a $p$-series with $p=j$ but where to go after that has me stumped. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change the order of summation (first on $j$, then on $k$), and rejoice.

Comment: If you *really* want to evaluate the sums in the current order, consider the Maclaurin expansion of the digamma function.

Comment: Sorry Did still not getting it. Do I calculate the sum of the outer series first?

Comment: Sorry Simply Beautiful Art, I have never heard of the digamma function?

Comment: Sorry Eiraus, are you asking Beautiful art whether you have never heard of the digamma function!

Comment: @Eiraus Have you ever heard of Google? Or seaching?

Comment: Also, please use @user to reply to someone.

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art I appreciate the help and I did google the digamma function. Waaay above my pay grade :-) do not understand it. Is there another way to approach the problem. Maybe somebody could expand on Dids explaniation?

Comment: @Eiraus Did's comment basically hints that you should use$$\sum_{j\ge2}\sum_{k\ge2}k^{-j}=\sum_{k\ge2}\sum_{j\ge2}k^{-j}$$

Comment: Sorry Eiraus but do you make it a matter of principle to reply to comments giving you explicit hints by comments stating you "do not get it" until a full solution is typed on the page? If you do not, what is it you "do not get" in my hint? Please be at least as specific as my comment is.

Comment: @Did My apologies but I did not simply type "I do not get it". I also followed up with the question "Do I calculate the sum of the outer series first?" meaning that I was looking for further clarification not a direct answer. Now that lisyarus has clarified what changing the order of summation means I understand but in my defence this is the first time I have encounter a series inside a series nor have I been taught that changing the order of summation is possible.

Comment: Sorry but what `Change the order of summation (first on j, then on k)` can mean, except what it actually means? Where do you see an ambiguity in the phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Did suggested in the comments, rearrange summation order:

$$\sum\limits_{j=2}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty k^{-j} = \sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\sum\limits_{j=2}^\infty k^{-j}$$

The inner sum is well-known, since it is a geometric progression with common ratio $\frac{1}{k}$:

$$\sum\limits_{j=2}^\infty k^{-j} = \sum\limits_{j=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^j} = \frac{1}{k^2}\left(1 + \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k^2} + \frac{1}{k^3} + \dots\right) = \frac{1}{k^2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{k}} = \frac{1}{k^2-k} = \frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}$$

Now this is clearly a telescopic series (note how everything except the first summand cancels out):

$$\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)= \left(\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4}\right)+\dots = 1 + \left(-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\right) + \left(-\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}\right) + \dots = 1$$

Comment: You have to justify that you can indeed rearrange the summation order with Fubini's theorem first, I think.

Comment: lisyarus Thank your for the in depth answer and @Mariuslp for the Fubini's theorem tip. I had no idea that changing the order of summation was a 'legal' move.

Answer (score 0):

You can make up the table:
$$\begin{array}{c|lccc|r}
a_{jk} & \text{} & \text{$k$} & \text{} & \text{} & \mathrm{Total}\\
\hline
 & \frac{1}{2^2} & \frac{1}{3^2} & \frac{1}{4^2} & \cdots \\
j & \frac{1}{2^3} & \frac{1}{3^3} & \frac{1}{4^3} & \cdots \\
  & \frac{1}{2^4} & \frac{1}{3^4} & \frac{1}{4^4} & \cdots \\
 & \ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\ 
\hline
\mathrm{Total} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2\cdot 3} & \frac{1}{3\cdot 4} & \cdots & 1 \ \ \ \
\end{array}$$
Note:
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m(m+1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m(m+1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[\frac12+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\right]=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[\left(1-\require{cancel}\cancel{\frac12}\right)+\left(\cancel{\frac{1}{2}}-\cancel{\frac13}\right)+\left(\cancel{\frac{1}{3}}-\cancel{\frac14}\right)+\cdots +\left(\cancel{\frac{1}{n}}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\right]=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right]=1.$$