# How to calculate double sum with power?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

How to calculate double sum with power like this?
$$\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \sum_{m = 2}^{\infty} m^{-n}$$
I have tried to search for the series formula equation but could not find one that fits for this. Is it possible to apply the geometric series formula to this one? If yes, how can we do it?

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28%20sum%20m%5E%28-n%29%20m%3D2..infinity%29%20n%3D2..infinity) gives me result $1$, but I don't know how can it be.

```
sum (sum m^(-n) m=2..infinity) n=2..infinity
```

Comment: Perhaps you can try to simplify only the innermost sum, by considering $n=2$ and then $n=3$ ... ?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2409883.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invert the order of the sums, do the geometric sum, partial fractions & telescope 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} m^{-n} & =& \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^2\left(1-\frac{1}{m} \right)}\\ 
& =&\sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m(m-1)} \\ 
& =&\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(m-1)} -\frac{1}{m}\right) =1. \\ 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: You've picked up a minus sign in the sums

Answer (score 3):

By Tonelli, this is $$\sum_{m=2}^\infty \frac{m^{-2}}{1-m^{-1}}=\sum_{m=2}^\infty \frac{1}{m^2-m}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\sum_{k=2}^t \frac1{k^2-k}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\sum_{k=2}^t \frac1{k-1}-\frac1k=\\=\lim_{t\to\infty}1-\frac1t$$